# Valid range for imshow with RGB data

Tags: python, matplotlib, image-processing

I am new to image processing, so this question might seem very basic. I want to visualize a collection of RGB images in Python. When I use the matplotlib's `imshow`, I get the following warning:

**Clipping input data to the valid range for imshow with RGB data ([0..1] for floats or [0..255] for integers).**

I understand that I can transform the ranges of RGB in my images to [0,1] using suitable *min* and *max* values, but I have the following questions:

1. Do I need to get these min and max values over the pixels of all the images or find them for each image separately?
2. Is there any relation between the min and max values of R, G, and B? I mean, do we transform each color independent of the other two?

Comment: The R,G,B values are **not** independent, if you change their relationship you change the color.

Comment: How are you obtaining images with values outside of those ranges?

Comment: @MarkRansom These images are given to me; the data is float, and its range is something like [-6,6].

Comment: if the range is [-6,+6], then I'd suggest calculating `(im+6) / 12` which is `(im - min) / (max - min)`

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz R, G, and B have different ranges (each around [-6,6]); do I need to get the min and max value across all colors and transform all RGB with the same min & max?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

Note: the variable `rgb` here refers to the `np.dstack` of the 3 Red, Green, and Blue images.

```
Image = rgb/np.amax(rgb) #cuz pixel values are ranged more than 0 and 1 
Image_clipped = np.clip(Image, 0, 1)  #if an interval of [0, 1] is specified, values smaller than 0 become 0, and values larger than 1 become 1.
plt.imshow(Image_clipped)
```

Comment: Thank you @personaltest25, why clip the data and not transform it to the [0,1] range?